# Dynamic Crafting Systems

Tags: java, game-mechanics

I have been toying with the idea of having a game that is based purely around crafting. That on its own is not much of a big deal. The way the crafting would work is the problem.

The idea I have is that there are a certain set of base materials with which the player can use to craft things. But aside from these set materials, anything goes. The player could combine the materials in any way they saw fit to create whatever they wanted. And then, with the new items the player has created, proceed to make more.

To me, this idea sounds very implausible and not able to be created. Is it actually possible?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be doable... Depending on how many items you would be able to craft, you would need a large database to store the resulting item codes and the materials needed to craft it.

Comment: @Savlon I don't think you are quite understanding... The point of this crafting system would be to have an infinite amount of recipe less items that could be crafted. You just have those base materials, and other items you have created.

Say, I start with a rock. I use a stick and a rock to make an axe. Then I use the axe and a shovel (previously made) to make something new again.

That is why I am asking this

Comment: Reminds me the Armadillo Run game. There are endless number of ways of making machinery from limited set of source materials. You can try and go this way, instead of "all resulting items are hardcoded in DB upfront".

Comment: There are already such games out there on same principle(more or less). I remember playing a mobile game with combining elements or animals to new crazy products, add some shaping of product and here we go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this question is going to be tagged and closed for being 'too broad', since it really is, so I will give a very general answer to a very general question.

What you are looking for is [Procedural Content Generation](http://pcg.wikidot.com/). Procedural Content Generation is the technique of using algorithms to generate a potentially infinite content for a game. You should read the linked website for a better insight.

There are tons of techniques which are applicable for tons of different types of contents, so I can't list on the top of my head which would suit better your game. One possible technique would be using a technique akin to [Genetic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming), where you take two existing items, mix their stats somehow, and introduce some mutation for variety.

Just keep in mind that if you truly want an infinite system, you will need to give up on rigid rules such as A+B = C, and let algorithms create content in your behalf.

Comment: I was wanting to avoid rigid rules - that was supposed to be the whole point of the system. Thanks for this, definitely what I was wanting to hear!

Answer (score 0):

What would you want the players to do with the items they create?
Will they be purely cosmetic, or actually have function to interact with (other) players, npcs, or the environment?

It's certainly doable, but in the second case you're going to need some form of scripting API for the crafters to script that interaction into the item.

And yes, it has been done. Check out Second Life (and its clones) which is essentially just that, apart from being a social network of course. Everything in the world is created by its inhabitants (or in a few places by the owners/creators of Second Life, using the exact same tools).
There's even a saying among SL builders "everything starts with a cube" (a .5x.5x.5 meter plywood cube is the default building block you get when you open the build window, it can be changed and twisted into all kind of things, as well as linked with others).
It also has a decent custom scripting language, allowing interaction among objects, parts of objects, avatars, the world as a whole, etc. etc..

Will you be able to write something like that on a sunday afternoon in your bedroom? No. Can it be done? Well, it has been done so surely it can be done but it's going to take a team of skilled software engineers several months to years to put together from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be overwhelmed.  I would recommend you start with 6 base items, and get the crafting mechanics up and running.  From there you can diagram out a crafting tree for yourself.  Try taking on one thing at a time, if you plan on having Blacksmithing, Carpentry, and Cooking, for example, just take on one of those mechanics.  Hopefully from there you can get a good idea of how you want your other crafting mechanics to work, and how you would want to structure your crafting tree.

Sometimes spending time with a notepad and a pen and removing yourself from a computer is the best way to let your imagination take over, while maintaining focus to get a clear idea of what items you want in your game, and how they can then be manipulated.